# Why can't we use RequestParameterRuleFilter in production?

Tags: java, oracle, atg

We are running into an interesting situation on a project where we're trying implement multisite functionality.

There is a component called RequestParameterRuleFilter that we are trying to use to override the “siteid” under certain circumstances.

Oracle's ATG documentation says that this component needs to be turned off in production, and we are trying to figure out why. Using this component saves us a lot of time, but we don’t want to risk any security holes or performance issues because of it.

Does anyone on here have any experience with this component, or know why we should not use this? Or, are there other alternative components built in to ATG that can be easily leveraged to provide multisite functionality?

Here is the link to the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35318_02/Platform.10-1-1/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0902installedrulefilters01.html

Comment: Please don't put tag information in the subject of your question. The tag system here is very well designed and doesn't need any assistance; it works perfectly well to place questions into appropriate categories and make them findable by those people interested in the subject of those tags. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Oracle E-Business Suite is an extremely specialist area,  You will be better off asking your question in the OTN EBS forum, because that's the place where OApps gurus hang out.  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=475

Comment: ATG has nothing to do with Oracle EBS, other than being owned by the same company. The best looking forum for asking this question would rather be https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1382

Answer (score 0):

I think site runs on domain name not on some param bases which can be manipulated easily, may be that y atg dosn't recommend this. We are using URLPatternMatchingRuleFilter, that resolve site based on domain name...and it is working fine...